# Android Copy Lists from one to another

Tags: android

I know its newbie question. I have 2 lists from same class.

```
List<A> list1 = new List<A>();
List<A> list2 = new List<A>();
```

how i can add items from `list1` to `list2` programaticly? I need to add 1 by 1 each item to `list2`.

Comment: List is absract you cant initiate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can do like this NOT LIST USING ANY CHILD CLASS LIKE ARRYLIST.

List<Your class name> list1 = new ArrayList();
List<Your class name> list2 = new ArrayList();
// populate lists here

 list1.addAll(list2) // will add all items of list2 in list 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Model> arrList1 = new ArrayList();
List<Model> arrList2 = new ArrayList(arrList1); // it will copy all records of arrList1 to arrList2.
```

Hope it useful for you.